# jQuery live span not updating until a second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, live, attr

To check this out please go to http://offline.raileisure.com/

on the right hand side the booking section, choose station masters house, then choose a check in date of 15 August. then choose 4 days...

OK

Now go back and choose a different date of 29th August.

The 4 days should deselect, but it doesn't until you do a further click anywhere else...

I think I need to be updating a live attr. but not sure.

to untick `#spanduration` I am using:

```
$('input[name="duration"]').removeAttr('checked');
$("#spanduration").attr("style", "background-position: 0px 0px;");
```

but it is not working until you do that second click anywhere.

Comment: are you using the jquery UI date picker?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it because its a radio button.

Try to change it to a checkbox?

Radio button dont like to be unchecked if none other is checked:

```
<input type="radio" value="0" name="duration">
<input type="radio" value="1" name="duration">
<input type="radio" value="2" name="duration">
<input type="radio" value="3" name="duration">
```

And standalone

```
<input type="radio" value="0" name="other_name">
```

On the other hand checkboxes uncheck each other: (note the name is array like)

```
<input type="checkbox" value="0" name="duration[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="duration[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="duration[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="duration[]">
```

And standalone

```
<input type="checkbox" value="0" name="other_name">
```

You can write something like this to have the ability of a standalone checkbox and also the sweetness of grouped radio-buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/LJJrZ/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selector = "input[type=checkbox]";
    $(selector).click(function(event){
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        if ( checked ) {
            $(selector).attr("checked", false);
            $(this).attr("checked", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The change event doesn't fire on a text input until the input is blurred.

You could try to manually blur the input after the date is populated (not great for accessibility). Or better yet, manually trigger the change event yourself after the date is populated. e.g.

```
//...
// After date is populated
$('#date').trigger('change');
//...
```

See full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/irama/rJGpn/

**EDIT**: Looking at your code, it looks like there's an opportunity (when you instantiate the datepicker) to insert this into a callback function:

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    // ...
    onSelect: function (e) {
        // ...

        $('#date').trigger('change');
    }
    // ...
```

Let us know how you go!

Comment: Hey @Lee how'd you go? Were you able to trigger the change? Let us know if you need any more help.